# Error while configuring redirect URL for Azure AD aplicattion to http://web/path through Azure Portal

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-mail

I am developing a website in php / javascript to send emails through Microsoft Outlook.

In the test server it works well because it is in localhost, but in the production server it does not work for me because it has http protocol.

When registering the redirect_url in the azure portal, ask for the protocol to be https or localhost.

Our server does not have https protocol. Is there any way to configure the application without https or do you know of another solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways you could do this -

1. Use legacy experience

   [image]

   Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations (Legacy) > Select "All apps" in drop down > Go you Your application's registration > Settings > Reply URLs

   [image]
2. Update the manifest

   Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > Your application's registration > Manifest

   [image]